# Ionic 3 Multiple select - Override button handlers

Tags: ionic2, multiple-select

I'm trying to override the behaviour of OK button on a multiple select component passing the [selectOptions]. The title and subtitle get overriden, but the buttons and the enableBackdropDismiss settings are ignored.
Anyone can help? Thanks in advance.

`<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Select roads</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedRoads" multiple="true" [selectOptions]="selectOptions">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let road of roads">{{road.description}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>`

`this.selectOptions = {
            title: 'Pizza Toppings',
            subTitle: 'Select your toppings',
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Cancel',
                    role: 'cancel',
                    handler: () => {
                        console.log('Cancel clicked');
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'Buy',
                    handler: () => {
                        console.log('Buy clicked');
                    }
                }
            ],
            enableBackdropDismiss:true
        };`

Comment: Do you use Alert, Popover or ActionSheet?

Comment: It's a multi select; accordingo to docs, popover and actionsheet are not available. it's an alert.

Comment: Can you please share more code to show how the select is created?

Comment: Edited the post with the html section. The options are taken, as i can see the title and subtitle in the app. The selectOptions are set on the constructor method.

Comment: @Diego78 were you able to figure this out?